# How to find Latitudes and Longitudes of projections of the vertices of a rectangular plane below earth's surface?

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I want to find out the latitudes and longitudes of projections of the vertices of a rectangular plane inside the earth's surface. I know dimensions of rectangle, angles of orientation and latitude and longitude of the projection of the center of the rectangle. please help. Earth's curvature is also to be considered

I added an Image which is a 2D representation of what i want. The plane actually is having 2 angles (its trace makes an angle 'A' with North and the plane makes an angle 'B' with the horizontal). I want to find lat longs of all 4 projections

[image]

Comment: This is not projective geometry.  Probably spherical coordinates for the vertices of your rectangle are what you're after.  You've said the rectangle is "inside the earth's surface", but this does not convey how it is oriented.

Comment: thnx! edited the tag.